# I have a question about React router dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Below code does not work in react router dom v6.

```
<Route path='/study-board' element={<StudyBoard />}>
    <Route path=':id' element={<StudyBoardDetail />} />
</Route>
```

But the code below works.

```
<Route path='/study-board/:id' element={<StudyBoardDetail />} />
```

Can you tell me what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `<outlet/>` to access nested routes
demo code

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />}>
        <Route path=":invoiceId" element={<Invoice />} />
        <Route path="sent" element={<SentInvoices />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}

function Invoices() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Invoices</h1>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

function Invoice() {
  let { invoiceId } = useParams();
  return <h1>Invoice {invoiceId}</h1>;
}

function SentInvoices() {
  return <h1>Sent Invoices</h1>;
}
```